# the detection of / the detecting of

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech

There is a famous sentence:

> This very superficial grammatist, supposing empty criticism about the
>   adoption of proper phraseology to be a show of extraordinary
>   erudition, was displaying, in spite of ridicule, a very boastful
>   turgid argument concerning the correction of false syntax, and about
>   the detection of false logic in debate.

In this sentence. I changed "detection" to "detecting" and I think it is still grammatically correct. Some say

> the detecting of false syntax

is grammatically wrong and there is no need to have "the" before and "of" after it (detecting false negative). What is more, they say it breaks the parallel structure with the previous part, "the correction of false syntax".

Is it correct to change "the detection of" to "the detecting of"?

Answer (score 0):

Detection is the noun associated with the verb, to detect. Detecting is only used as the gerund in my opinion and it doesn’t sound correct in this context; detection is preferred

Comment: Thank you very much. Does "is preferred" mean that the other one is correct but not preferred or completely wrong?